# C# authenticate against a remote kerberos kdc

Tags: c#, authentication, kerberos, jaas, sspi

Context: Let's say you were writing a program that provides a service for university students, and you needed to make sure only the particular university's students had access to it. That university, like most, gives its students kerberos logins.

How would one go about authenticating users against a pre-existing, remote kerberos v5 kdc as described above in c#? The goal is to simply authenticate (pass/fail), I am not looking to store any tickets/tokens.

I have done the same thing in Java using [JAAS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jaas/tutorials/GeneralAcnOnly.html) (Java Authentication and Authorization Service) and it was very straight forward.

Is SSPI the equivalent in .NET? How do I use it to accomplish what I need? I can't seem to find code examples that do this.

Note: I have already looked at @chimanrao 's [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8005139/c-sharp-client-to-connect-to-kerberos-kdc) and the links did not discuss this specific issue in enough detail for me. Also, the [mdsn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82tywhc6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) on this topic is grossly incomplete, some of the classes it speaks of don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to do the same thing.  I was recently given a project from my company where I must require users to enter their windows login and password into a form on a web page, and when submitted, I need to authenticate against a remote Active Directory server.  All I need is a pass/fail as well, no tokens necessary.